# how to import data from a csv file to a xlsm

Tags: excel, vba

Currently trying to import data from a CSV file using a command button. When I run the button I do not receive any errors, however nothing is printed out.

```
Private Sub CommandButton23_Click()
Dim Next_Row As Long
    Next_Row = 1

File = Application.GetOpenFilename _
        ("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Select the CSV file", , False)

    If File = False Then
        MsgBox_Response = MsgBox("File could not be opened or is not compatible", vbOKOnly)
        Else
        Open File For Input As #1

        row_number = 1
      Do Until EOF(1)

            Line Input #1, LineFromFile

            LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
          Loop
          End If

        row_number = row_number + 1
        Debug.Print LineFromFile
    Close #1

End Sub
```

im wanting all the data from the csv file to print out onto another worksheet where I have some macros set up.

Comment: Your loop will only show the last `LineFromFile` I think this `Debug.Print LineFromFile` needs to be in the loop

Comment: hmmm that didnt seem to change anything thanks though @Nathan_Sav

Answer (score 1):

I think you've just got the wrong structure to your code

```
Dim File As Variant
Dim MsgBox_Response As Long
Dim LineFromFile As String
Dim LineItems As Variant
Dim RowCounter As Long

File = Application.GetOpenFilename _
("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Select the CSV file", , False)

If File = False Then
    MsgBox_Response = MsgBox("File could not be opened or is not compatible", vbOKOnly)
Else
    Open File For Input As #1

    ' Update this with your sheet reference
    With Sheet1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, LineFromFile

            LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
            ' Increment row counter
            RowCounter = RowCounter + 1
            .Range("A" & RowCounter).Resize(, UBound(LineItems) + IIf(LBound(LineItems) = 0, 1, 0)).Value2 = LineItems
            Debug.Print Join(LineItems, vbTab)
        Loop
    End With
    Close #1
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Tom although it still isn't outputting anything. So i think there must be somthing fundmentally wrong with my code. many thanks for tidying it up and formating it correctly!

Comment: Check the formatting of your csv file. See if it opens correctly in Excel

Comment: there are no issues when opening the CSV file in excel it opens correctly in format i expect it to.

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but where are you checking for it to be outputted to?

Comment: im wanting it to output on to the worksheet with the button. so i've got a worksheet with this command button and some other command buttons which use the data from the CSV file but currently im having to paste over the data after opening it in another excel doc due to this button not printing out the CSV data. Hopefully this makes sense. thanks

Comment: @GreenerGreen `Debug.Print` will output to the immediate window in the VBA editor. It won't output to your sheet. I suspect the code above is working fine. You're just expecting it to be in the incorrect place. Have a look at my updated code - update with your sheet reference. It will output into Column A from row 1